# SELECT subquery within IN statement hanging SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

curious about this behavior from SQL Server.

This query produces results very quickly, just as I'd expect:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.v_View1 View1 FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.v_View2 View2 ON View1.Portfolio = View2.Portfolio AND 
    View1.AsOfDate = View2.AsOfDate
where (View1.AsOfDate IN (NULL, '20130717'))
```

However, I don't want to have a static date in there, so I replaced it with a subquery.  Unfortunately, the longest I've waited for this query to execute is 5 minutes before I cancelled it, so I don't know if it actually would get me the data I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.v_View1 View1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     dbo.v_View2 View2 ON View1.Portfolio = View2.Portfolio AND 
     View1.AsOfDate = View2.AsOfDate
where (View1.AsOfDate IN (NULL, (SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) FROM dbo.v_View1)))
```

I've resorted to declaring a variable, setting it with the subquery from above, and using that in the IN statement, which works as expected and runs just about as quickly as the original query.

I know I'm doing something wrong or missing something (probably both) - what is it?  I'd like to have the subquery within the IN statement, or at least be able to run this as a view without variables.  Thanks!

Comment: Look at the execution plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the query optimizer is doing something very strange because the naive implementation involves two scans on `v_View1` perhaps the optimizer is failing to realize that the subquery `SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) ...` is going to be the same for each row. I suspect it might be failing to realize that the subquery is not correlated to each row and thus running it for every row of your result set. Given the full outer join, with a lot of data that means a lot of unnecessary table scans.

The simple solution is:

```
DECLARE @MaxAsOfDate datetime;
SET @MaxAsOfDate = (SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) FROM dbo.v_View1)

SELECT *
FROM dbo.v_View1 View1 FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.v_View2 View2 ON View1.Portfolio = View2.Portfolio AND 
    View1.AsOfDate = View2.AsOfDate
where (View1.AsOfDate IN (NULL, @MaxAsOfDate))
```

And that will force the subquery to run once, store the result in the variable, and then use that for the following query.

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing that within a stored procedure instead of within the view this was supposed to be (that seemed more 'correct' as the View designer doesn't have visual support for variables), but was hoping I was just missing something.  Oh well - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is recalculating MAX(AsOfDate) for every record it comapres to.  A simple solution would be to use a WITH clause (also known as common table expression) which would only be calculated at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest using the top one and changing it so it dont have the NULL on the IN statement so write it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.v_View1 View1 FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.v_View2 View2 ON View1.Portfolio = View2.Portfolio AND 
    View1.AsOfDate = View2.AsOfDate
where View1.AsOfDate IN ('20130717') AND View1.AsOfDate IS NULL
```

also is a FULL OUTER JOIN needed? or could a INNER JOIN be used?

also if you take a look at the execution plan and post that i will be able to post more information on how to best optimize this query you will also see on what point the query is taking the longest

[image: Picture of execution plan and how to show it]

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't fix the issue where I'm trying to have a dynamic AsOfDate in the `WHERE` statement.  I'll take a look at the execution plan and see if there's something fishy in there, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to rewrite this, to avoid the problem, is:

```
where View1.AsOfDate is null or View1.AsOfDate = (SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) FROM dbo.v_View1)
```

EDIT:

Your problem is *not* that the query is running multiple times.  Your problem is that the view is highly unoptimized.  You can probably fix this just by recompiling the view.  Script it out as an `ALTER` statement in SSMS and execute that.  The underlying tables have probably changed since the view was created.

I think you can also fix this by telling SQL Server not to use nested loop joins (this is the cause of your performance problem).  You can do so by add `option (hash join, merge join)` to the end of the SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, but this is producing the same issue for me - currently has run for 5 minutes.